# c++ ostream return data from objects array

Tags: c++, ostream

I've the following source code for my ostream

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, AnimalsDirectory& a) {
   for(int i=0;i<a.directorySize;i++) {
      return os << a.animals[i];
   }
}
```

When I compile this code it produces me the following error:

```
ContactDir.cpp:64:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void 
function
  [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
```

I don't know why this error occurs, I do it on objects animals array and want '<<' print all info about what this array has.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `c.directorySize`? I cannot see any `c` object in your `operator <<` Furthermore, the very first `return` statement will terminate your loop and you will **only** return `a.animals[0]`

Comment: @Fureeish I fixed it above, there was a

Comment: so how to loop on all objects and return data about it ?

Comment: yo should write to the ostream all you need to, and then return it at the end

Comment: `return os << a.animals[i];` on the first iteration of the loop, this will return from the function. Unfortunately, if `directorySize` is 0, this will never execute, and the loop ends, but the function does not then explicitly return anything. That's what your compiler is complaining about. This `return` statement is clearly in error, you meant to print every element in the array, without returning, and have a single `return` statement at the end.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik can you write here any implementation for it ?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't know how to change it

Comment: What exactly you "don't know", here? There's nothing here that requires any additional knowledge beyond the one that was needed to write this code in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look how the operator method you want to implement is declared.
You have to return a reference to a ostream object which is the one you get in your first parameter.

Secondly you have a return statement in your loop which will quit the function in the first loop cycle. What you probably want to do is something like this

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, AnimalsDirectory& a) {
    for(int i=0;i<a.directorySize;i++) {
       os << a.animals[i];
    }
    return os;
}
```

This requires that each animal object has also the <<-operator implemented

Answer (score 0):

```
   for(int i=0;i<a.directorySize;i++) {
      return os << a.animals[i];
   }
```

Let's see.. what if `a.directorySize == 0`?, then `i < a.directorySize` is false for `i = 0` which means the loop never runs, which means the `return` statement will not be reached. This invokes undefined behavior as there is nothing to return after the loop. For this the compiler issues a warning.

Furthermore, your code looks odd to say the least, you usually never loop only to unconditionally return.

Comment: Ok, so what do you prefer for me ? Have you got any idea on implementation ?